# Am I using the chi-squared test correctly?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, chi-squared-test, uniform-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I have a set of $2,142$ measurements of some value that are grouped into $18$ bins of equal length (according to the value measured). I want to check the resulting distribution for uniformity.

As far as I understand, the standard procedure for this is using the $\chi^2$ test. So I used the formula (took it from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)), where I summed the squares of deviations from the expected value (the latter being $2142/18 = 119$) divided by the expected value itself, and I got the result of $159.966$.

As far as [p-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Computational_methods) go, this is much larger than even 0.001 requires ($10.83$ for $1$ degree of freedom), which looks suspicious to me. Hence my doubts.

Do I actually have $1$ degree of freedom? Or is it $18$ degrees of freedom in reality? (Just in case I'll repeat that it's the same variable, just different values thereof).

Did I calculate the $\chi^2$ correctly in the first place? And if I did, how do I get the actual p-value?

For the reference, the frequency values of my bins are:

```
44, 139, 155, 127, 117, 119, 158, 129, 105, 109, 122, 120, 113, 142, 119, 154, 138, 32
```

And the histogram looks like this: [image]

Comment: "p-values go, this is much larger than even 0.001" you mean *smaller*, surely. The p-value is smaller than 0.001 at 1 d.f. But the d.f parameter is not 1, nor is it 18. How were the bins for the histogram selected? Based on the data? Or chosen before you had data? If the former, the chi-squared test of goodness of fit will not apply as is. Are the limits on the uniform specified before hand or based on the data? Again, if not pre-specified, you don't have a chi-squared test as is.

Comment: It's based on observational error of the measured value (each bin is double its value in size). 
I don't really understand what "limits on the uniform" means. If you mean the maximum and minimum values (1st and 18th bin), then they represent the full scope of possible outcomes (these are angles between two 3D vectors with 10 degree resolution).
Which tests would apply in this case?

Comment: "It's based on observational error of the measured value (each bin is double its value in size)." It would be a very good idea to explain what's going on here in some detail, in your question.

Comment: Late to this thread. but the underlying measurement is now revealed to be a continuous angle, so any binning is utterly arbitrary and a chi-square test somewhere between inefficient and pointless. That is, why not bin widths of 20, 5, 2, 1, etc.?  I agree with @Shawn Hemelstrand that the fine structure at the ends is notable. I wouldn't use a chi-square test here at all. The most appropriate test in my view would be essentially graphical: a line-up test to compare a quantile plot of the raw data with a bundle of quantile plots using several samples of the same size from a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if each of these bins represents its own category, then there are two issues. One, we need to know why they are binned from a theoretical perspective. Are they binned into something meaningful (such as species of animals) or are they binned into something arbitrary (such as $10> x > 20$)?

Second, if these binned values are indeed your groups, your degrees of freedom are certainly incorrect. For a chi-square test of uniformity, you typically just find degrees of freedom with $k-1$, where $k$ is the number of groups. As you have $18$ bins, which I assume to be all independent groups, this would mean that you have $17$ degrees of freedom.

Running this through R confirms this:

```r
#### Create Data ####
count <- c(44,139,155,127,117,119,
           158,129,105,109,122,120,
           113,142,119,154,138,32)
group <- factor(1:18)
df <- data.frame(group,count)
head(df)

#### Run Chi-Square ####
chisq.test(df$count)
```

Which gives us this result with the corresponding expected degrees of freedom:

Chi-squared test for given probabilities

```r
data:  df$count
X-squared = 159.97, df = 17, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

You will notice the p-value and $\chi^2$ are still the same. Just looks like your degrees of freedom were not correct.

If you're wondering why its chi-square is so high, our guess should be that the outer two groups of your histogram are weighting this decision. As most of the other groups have pretty uniform counts, these two outside groups stand in stark contrast to the others, which may have shifted the chi-square value consequently. This is because, as part of the test, you check the differences between expected counts and observed counts. If the observed counts are very different from what's expected, you consequently get larger chi values. Checking again in R, we can find this directly by using the operations used in this test:

```r
#### Get Expected Values ####
expected <- sum(count)/18
expected

#### Check Scores ####
df %>% 
  mutate(diffs = count-expected, # difference scores
         sq.diffs = diffs^2,# squared differences
         chi = sq.diffs/expected) # chi values
```

Which you can see that indeed the first and last group are the highest:

````r
       group count diffs sq.diffs          chi
    1      1    44   -75     5625 47.268907563
    2      2   139    20      400  3.361344538
    3      3   155    36     1296 10.890756303
    4      4   127     8       64  0.537815126
    5      5   117    -2        4  0.033613445
    6      6   119     0        0  0.000000000
    7      7   158    39     1521 12.781512605
    8      8   129    10      100  0.840336134
    9      9   105   -14      196  1.647058824
    10    10   109   -10      100  0.840336134
    11    11   122     3        9  0.075630252
    12    12   120     1        1  0.008403361
    13    13   113    -6       36  0.302521008
    14    14   142    23      529  4.445378151
    15    15   119     0        0  0.000000000
    16    16   154    35     1225 10.294117647
    17    17   138    19      361  3.033613445
    18    18    32   -87     7569 63.605042017
``
Summing these up, we get our chi:
```r  
df %>% 
  mutate(diffs = count-expected,
         sq.diffs = diffs^2,
         chi = sq.diffs/expected) %>% 
  summarise(sum.chi = sum(chi)) # just added this
````

Which matches our expectation:

```r
       sum.chi
    1 159.9664
```

Because you were misled about the critical chi-square value, this may be why you are partly skeptical. This larger chi-square table shows the critical value is $27.587$ (assuming you set your alpha at $.05$):

[image]

Comment: The bins are angles from 0 to 180 with a 10 degree resolution (in each experiment I'm measuring the angle between two supposedly independent 3-dimensional vectors). 
Follow-up questions:
1) Maybe that would imply that I have 2 degrees of freedom? (As 2 vectors are involved). Or even 6? (By the number of coordinates).
2) I can change the resolution arbitrarily. In principle, I can reduce it to 1 degree and get 180 bins (however, my observational error is around 5 degrees). Is it generally more advisable to have higher resolution?

Comment: If you think 10 degree groupings are theoretically justifiable in some way, then you can use them. For example, do you have a-priori presuppositions as to why that would be the case? Do you expect some degree positions to be very different from the others? Or do you believe there is a linear relationship (e.g. as resolution increases, so does the DV)? Nobody can answer these theoretical justifications other than yourself. I think just picking whatever grouping looks right after you obtain your data is not very scientific. This should be thought up ahead of time.

Comment: @EugeneB. The degrees of freedom are governed by the number of bins (minus one), regardless of where the counts ultimately came from (as long as the single events counted can be treated as independent). However, if you start experimenting around with other ways of doing things, you'll get into the territory of multiple testing and potential model selection bias.

Comment: @EugeneB: "I'm measuring the angle between two supposedly independent 3-dimensional vectors" Independence does not imply a uniform distribution of the angle between them. Even if we assume both vectors are spherical symmetrically distributed, their angle would be more concentrated around 90 degrees.

Comment: As a small but telling detail, I would not use $n$ to denote number of categories, as it's all too likely to be confused with a conventional choice of $n$ for number of observations (data points). $k$ is one of several letters that would work better.

Comment: That certainly makes sense. I have edited it for clarity.

Answer (score 8):

To add to the answer of @Shawn Hemelstrand, you have to keep in mind that generally, in statistical tests, if you have a large sample, you can have very small (highly significant) p-values even if the deviation from the null hypothesis is not so strong. The p-value does *not* measure the difference between your data and the null hypothesis, but rather how strongly the data indicate *any* difference, and even a weak difference can lead to a strong indication against the null hypothesis if the sample is large. Under uniformity over 18 bins, it is pretty much impossible to have a range of frequencies between 32 and 158, and this is what the p-value (the correct one as given in @Shawn Hemelstrand's answer) indicates. With 1/10 amount of data, bin frequencies between 3 and 16, say, could much easier happen under uniformity.

Comment: +1 for an important point. As indicated by Christian, this does not indicate the magnitude of the effect. We can only decide with this test whether or not we can reject the null. One can consider adding additional nominal association values like those [listed here](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~pdattalo/702SuppRead/MeasAssoc/NominalAssoc.html#:~:text=Phi%20is%20a%20chi%2Dsquare,and%20taking%20the%20square%20root.)